# javafx bindAutoCompletion on textArea

Tags: javafx, data-binding, textarea, bind, textfield

Is is possible to use bindAutoCompletion on TextArea, like:

```
        String[] autosuggestions = {"test","testing","etc etc"};
    TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(inputTextArea, autosuggestions);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use javaFx's library [controlsFx](https://gluonhq.com/controlsfx/) to use textfield's auto-completion here is a sample code on their [website](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/79988213/)

Comment: i know im asking for TEXTAREA

Comment: you can tweak this sample to meet your requirements